# What's the meaning of double dots in controls syntax of tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

What's the meaning of dots in this syntax?

.. controls 〈 first control point 〉 and 〈 second control point 〉 .. 〈 end point 〉

Comment: Welcome! This constructs a cubic Bezier path (because you specify two control points). If you had specified one control point, this would be a quadratic Bezier path. See section **2.4 Curved Path Construction** of pgfmanual v3.1.5. A possible analytic parametrization of such paths can be found in equation (1) in section **46.2 Computing the Bounding Box** of the same manual.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was just wondering why it needs two dots surrounding 'controls'. It's a little weird for newbies like me.  @Schrödinger'scat

Comment: This is just some syntax. Other tools like `asymptote` or `metapost` have, if I remember correctly, similar syntax conventions.

Comment: Thank you! @Schrödinger'scat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This constructs a cubic Bezier curve. You can find explanations in section **2.4 Curved Path Construction** of pgfmanual v3.1.5

[image]

Ti*k*Z has a decoration called `show path construction`, see the pgfmanual 3.1.5 on p. 645. It can be used to illustrate the point again, and also to provide you a tool that you can play with to get a feeling for this path construction.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, dot/.style={circle,fill,radius=1pt,inner sep=1pt},
every label/.append style={font=\tiny\ttfamily},
decoration={show path construction, 
moveto code={},
lineto code={},
curveto code={
\draw [green!75!black,->] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls
(\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) ..(\tikzinputsegmentlast)
 node [above,midway, sloped, font=\tiny] {curveto};
\draw[dashed] 
(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) 
node[dot,label=below:\textbackslash tikzinputsegmentfirst] {}
-- (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta)
node[dot,label=above:\textbackslash tikzinputsegmentsupporta] {}
(\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
node[dot,label=above:\textbackslash tikzinputsegmentsupportb] {}
 -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast)
 node[dot,label=below:\textbackslash tikzinputsegmentlast] {};
},
closepath code={}
}]
\draw [help lines] grid (6,2);
\draw[decorate] (0,0) .. controls (1,2) and (5.5,2) .. (6,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the dashed lines connecting the start point and the first control point, or the end point and the second control point, are tangents to the curve.

You can find tons of other ways to construct curved paths, but internally they always get translated to a series `lineto` operations (straight lines), `curveto` operations (Bezier curves), some `moveto` and some `closepath` operations. I personally hardly ever use Bezier curves explicitly to construct curves. Apart from the various constructions mentioned in the pgfmanual one may want to honorably mention the `hobby` library which is an excellent tool for constructing curves in an intuitive way.